# Should I add the primary key in my sql server index?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I know any non clustered index contains the primary key. But I wonder if it contains it in a specific order or not.

I have a query which retrieve for every "MemberTee" its most recent (highest ID) "MemberTeeHist"'s teeID value.

```
SELECT
    MT.ID
    , MTH.teeID
FROM Favorite.tMemberTee AS MT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MTH.memberTeeID
        , MTH.teeID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MTH.memberTeeID ORDER BY MTH.ID DESC) AS RNK
    FROM Favorite.tMemberTeeHist AS MTH
) AS MTH ON (
    MTH.memberTeeID = MT.ID
    AND
    MTH.RNK = 1
)
```

In order for this query to perform the best, I need an index on `tMemberTeeHist` ordered by memberTeeID and ID (primary key).

Here are the tables DDL :

```
CREATE SCHEMA Favorite
GO

CREATE TABLE Favorite.tMemberTee (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tMemberTee PRIMARY KEY (ID)

    , memberID BIGINT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tMemberTee_memberID FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES dbo.tMembers(ID)
    , courseID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tMemberTee_courseID FOREIGN KEY (courseID) REFERENCES dbo.tCourseBases(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , CONSTRAINT UQ_tMemberTee_01 UNIQUE (courseID, memberID)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Favorite.tMemberTeeHist (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tMemberTeeHist PRIMARY KEY (ID)

    , memberTeeID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tMemberTeeHist_memberTeeID FOREIGN KEY (memberTeeID) REFERENCES Favorite.tMemberTee(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    , teeID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tMemberTeeHist_teeID FOREIGN KEY (teeID) REFERENCES dbo.tTees(ID)

    , [date] DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_tMemberTeeHist_date DEFAULT GETDATE()
    , originatorID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tMemberTeeHist_originatorID FOREIGN KEY (originatorID) REFERENCES dbo.tClubMembers(ID)
)
GO
```

Now, should I create the index this way (because SQL SERVER would already internally have ID ordered inside the index) :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tMemberTeeHist_memberTeeID ON Favorite.tMemberTeeHist (memberTeeID ASC) 
GO
```

Or should I have it like this :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_tMemberTeeHist_memberTeeID ON Favorite.tMemberTeeHist (memberTeeID ASC, ID ASC) 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the constraint

```
CONSTRAINT PK_tMemberTee PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

creates a default, **clustered** primary key (and thus a clustered index), that clustering column `ID` is **already** part of every nonclustered index (at the leaf level) anyway

There's no point or no benefit in adding it in separately again.

Comment: I know it will be part of it, but since it's part of it at leaf level, does it mean it won't be ordered thus for a specific range of the indexed column, will sql server have to scan all the range to find the highest ID (primary key)?

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook: yes, that is correct - the clustering key by default is available only at the leaf level, e.g. it is not part of the "navigation structure" of the non-clustered index and cannot be part of a `WHERE` clause. If you need that, then you need to create a non-clustered index *with* the clustering key as part of the index definition (as you had shown in your question)